# mongoose-aggregate-pagination-v2: aggregatePagination isn't working properly

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I have 2 collections: User and Topic. This is what each model look like.

```
- User -
{
  _id: ObjectId
  ...
  topics: [ObjectId(topic1Id), ObjectId(topic2Id)]
}
```

```
- Topic -
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   ...,
   author: ObjectId(authorId)
}
```

I'm trying to get all topics that belong to one user and paginate those topics. Below is the query I'm using:

```
const aggregate = await Topic.aggregate([{ $match: { author: user._id } }]);
const result = await Topic.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, {page: 1, limit: 2} };
```

The result I got back includes all Topic documents, instead of the ones that match the query in `$match`. I did some console.log and `aggregate` returns the correct docs but for some reason, when it goes through `aggregatePaginate`, all docs are returned to me.
I did make sure that the `user._id` is an ObjectId so that's not a problem.

Please let me know if you need anymore details and please help, I've been spending hours on this and I can't figure it out :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2) ensure you have imported the module:

```js
const aggregatePaginate = require("mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2");
```

or

```js
import aggregatePaginate from "mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2";
```

Then register it as a plugin:

```js
topicSchema.plugin(aggregatePaginate);
```

Now all you need to do is construct your aggregate without executing it like so, this means no `await` keyword or `then` blocks:

```js
const aggregate = Topic.aggregate([{ $match: { author: user._id } }]);
```

The `aggregate` then gets passed to your query:

```js
const result = await Topic.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, {page: 1, limit: 2} };
```

Comment: It's working now! I just needed to remove the `await` before the `Topic.aggregate`. You're my savior, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. This is not very clear in the official docs.